# Rails one liner email sending?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

How can I send an email in one line without creating a mailer class?

I need to set all the params including :from (which is different than the smtp user)

So far I got this:

```
# ok not exactly a one liner, but it doesn't matter
ActionMailer::Base.mail(:from => 'admin@mysite.me', :to => 'someone@gmail.com', :subject => 'subject bla') do
  'content bla'
end.deliver
```

The content is not working, I receive a blank email

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
ActionMailer::Base.mail(from: 'from@domain.com', to: 'to@domain.com', subject: "Welcome to My Awesome Site", body: 'I am the email body.').deliver
```

Omg, we have one-liner!

Comment: No need to be arrogant. In fact, that doesn't even work without any changes. I guess I need to force the request format to text. How can I do that?

Comment: I can't believe :body actually worked. In other post I used it because that option had to exist, and someone pointed me to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) and told me it didn't exist.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L683 undocumented != nonexistent, I guess.